# App Store not allowing me to upgrade to Sierra

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade from El Capitan 10.11.6 to the latest version of Sierra 10.12.x.

I'm following [this tutorial](https://macpaw.com/how-to/how-to-upgrade-your-mac-to-macos-sierra) which recommends getting Sierra through the **App Store**.

However when I open the App Store and go to the **Updates** tab, I do not see Sierra as an option, only upgrading security patches for my existing 10.11.6 installation:

[image]

**What's going on here? How can I find 10.12.x and upgrade to it?**

Comment: What happens if you search for Sierra in the Search box?

Comment: FWIW, the link to Sierra in the app store for me is https://itunes.apple.com/ie/app/macos-sierra/id1127487414. You may need to replace 'ie' with your country code, e.g. 'us', 'ca', etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget that guide. It is incorrect at this point and giving you misleading instructions.

The **Update** tab is *only* for **updates** for *your currently running system.*

As you phrased correctly in your question title, you want an **upgrade**.

That means a completely new system.

Currently, the Sierra installer – or upgrade – is on the first tab. The Featured-tab marked with a star. Top link on the right. Text only.

You may also search for "macOS Sierra" in the search box, upper right corner.

All respecting the prerequisite that your machine is supported for this kind of upgrade.